# DirectX installed on Wine althought it doesn't work in games

Tags: graphics, wine, directx

I have installed DirectX on Wine and used winetricks to have better graphics in my games. Although it doesn't work! When I want to run GTA: San Andreas it shows that I have to download and install DirectX. In other games, exactly nothing happens. I do not know what the matter is. There is a log from `dxdiag`:

```
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 7/25/2014, 14:37:07
       Machine name: localhost
   Operating System: Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3
           Language: English (Regional Setting: Polish)
System Manufacturer: The Wine Project
       System Model: Wine
               BIOS: Default System BIOS
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.1GHz
             Memory: 3880MB RAM
          Page File: 1144MB used, 10758MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     DxDiag Version: 5.03.0001.0904 32bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
  DirectX Files Tab: Several files (dxapi.sys, d3d8thk.dll, d3dim700.dll, etc.) are missing! The file qedit.dll is an old version, which could cause problems. You should reinstall DirectX to get the latest version.
      Display Tab 1: The file  is not digitally signed, which means that it has not been tested by Microsoft's Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).  You may be able to get a WHQL logo'd driver from the hardware manufacturer. Problems were found in the system registry.  Details are available in the saved text file. You should reinstall DirectX to get the latest version.
        Sound Tab 1: The file winemm.vxd is not digitally signed, which means that it has not been tested by Microsoft's Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).  You may be able to get a WHQL logo'd driver from the hardware manufacturer.
        Sound Tab 2: The file winemm.vxd is not digitally signed, which means that it has not been tested by Microsoft's Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).  You may be able to get a WHQL logo'd driver from the hardware manufacturer.
        Sound Tab 3: The file winemm.vxd is not digitally signed, which means that it has not been tested by Microsoft's Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).  You may be able to get a WHQL logo'd driver from the hardware manufacturer.
        Sound Tab 4: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 5: The file winemm.vxd is not digitally signed, which means that it has not been tested by Microsoft's Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).  You may be able to get a WHQL logo'd driver from the hardware manufacturer.
          Music Tab: The specified General MIDI DLS file was not found.
          Input Tab: Problems were found in the system registry.  Details are available in the saved text file.
        Network Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (n/a)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (n/a)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (n/a)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
        Card name: X11 Windowing System
     Manufacturer: 
        Chip type: 
         DAC type: 
       Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_0000&DEV_0000
   Display Memory: 132.0 MB
     Current Mode: 1366 x 768 (32 bit)
          Monitor: X11 Windowing System
  Monitor Max Res: 
      Driver Name: 
   Driver Version:  ()
      DDI Version: 9 (or higher)
Driver Attributes: Final Retail
 Driver Date/Size: , 0 bytes
      WHQL Logo'd: No
  WHQL Date Stamp: None
              VDD: n/d
         Mini VDD: 
    Mini VDD Date: n/a, 0 bytes
Device Identifier: {AEB2CDD4-6E41-43EA-941C-8361CC760781}
        Vendor ID: 0x10DE
        Device ID: 0x0302
        SubSys ID: 0x00000000
      Revision ID: 0x0000
      Revision ID: 0x0000
      Video Accel: 
 Deinterlace Caps: n/a

Registry Errors Found:
Key 'HKCR\CLSID\{4516EC43-8F20-11d0-9B6D-0000C0781BC3}\InprocServer32', Value '', should be 'd3dxof.dll'
Key 'HKCR\DirectXFile\CLSID' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\DirectXFile' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\CLSID\{4516EC41-8F20-11d0-9B6D-0000C0781BC3}\InprocServer32' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\CLSID\{4516EC41-8F20-11d0-9B6D-0000C0781BC3}\InprocServer32' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\CLSID\{4516EC41-8F20-11d0-9B6D-0000C0781BC3}' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\Direct3DRM\CLSID' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\Direct3DRM' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\DX6TextureEnumInclusionList\8 bit Luminance' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\DX6TextureEnumInclusionList\24 bit BumpLum DuDv' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\DX6TextureEnumInclusionList\16 bit Luminance Alpha' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\DX6TextureEnumInclusionList\16 bit BumpLum DuDv' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\DX6TextureEnumInclusionList\16 bit Bump DuDv' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers\RGB Emulation' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers\RGB Emulation' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers\Ramp Emulation' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers\Ramp Emulation' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers\Ramp Emulation' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers\Direct3D HAL' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers\Direct3D HAL' is missing.
Key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Direct3D\Drivers\Direct3D HAL' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\DirectDrawClipper\CLSID' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\DirectDrawClipper' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\DirectDraw\CLSID' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\DirectDraw' is missing.

     DDraw Status: Enabled
       D3D Status: Enabled
       AGP Status: Not Available
DDraw Test Result: Not run
 D3D7 Test Result: Not run
 D3D8 Test Result: Not run
 D3D9 Test Result: Not run

-------------
Sound Devices
-------------
            Description: Out: default
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
 Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: 
        Manufacturer ID: 
             Product ID: 
                   Type: VXD
            Driver Name: winemm.vxd
         Driver Version:  ()
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: No
          Date and Size: , 0 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: 
         HW Accel Level: Unknown
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No
               Registry: OK
      Sound Test Result: Not run

            Description: Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 2
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: 
        Manufacturer ID: 
             Product ID: 
                   Type: VXD
            Driver Name: winemm.vxd
         Driver Version:  ()
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: No
          Date and Size: , 0 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: 
         HW Accel Level: Unknown
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No
               Registry: OK
      Sound Test Result: Not run

            Description: Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 0
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: 
        Manufacturer ID: 
             Product ID: 
                   Type: VXD
            Driver Name: winemm.vxd
         Driver Version:  ()
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: No
          Date and Size: , 0 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: 
         HW Accel Level: Unknown
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No
               Registry: OK
      Sound Test Result: Not run

            Description: Out: HDA Intel PCH - CX20757 Analog
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: 
        Manufacturer ID: 
             Product ID: 
                   Type: VXD
            Driver Name: winemm.vxd
         Driver Version:  ()
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: , 0 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: 
         HW Accel Level: Unknown
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No
               Registry: OK
      Sound Test Result: Not run

            Description: Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 1
 Default Sound Playback: No
 Default Voice Playback: No
            Hardware ID: 
        Manufacturer ID: 
             Product ID: 
                   Type: VXD
            Driver Name: winemm.vxd
         Driver Version:  ()
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: No
          Date and Size: , 0 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: 
         HW Accel Level: Unknown
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No
               Registry: OK
      Sound Test Result: Not run

---------------------
Sound Capture Devices
---------------------
            Description: In: default
  Default Sound Capture: Yes
  Default Voice Capture: Yes
            Driver Name: winemm.vxd
         Driver Version:  ()
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: , 0 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x0
           Format Flags: 0xFFFFF

            Description: In: HDA Intel PCH - CX20757 Analog
  Default Sound Capture: No
  Default Voice Capture: No
            Driver Name: winemm.vxd
         Driver Version:  ()
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: , 0 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x0
           Format Flags: 0xFFFFF

-----------
DirectMusic
-----------
        DLS Path: C:\windows\system32\drivers\gm.dls
     DLS Version: 
    Acceleration: n/a
           Ports: Microsoft Synthesizer, Software (Not Kernel Mode), Output, DLS, Internal, Default Port
                  Wine midi mapper [Emulowany], Hardware (Not Kernel Mode), Output, No DLS, Internal
                  Midi Through Port-0 [Emulowany], Hardware (Not Kernel Mode), Output, No DLS, External
                  Midi Through Port-0 [Emulowany], Hardware (Not Kernel Mode), Input, No DLS, External
        Registry: OK
     Test Result: Not run

-------------------
DirectInput Devices
-------------------
      Device Name: Mouse
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

      Device Name: Keyboard
         Attached: 1
    Controller ID: n/a
Vendor/Product ID: n/a
        FF Driver: n/a

Poll w/ Interrupt: No
         Registry: Errors found
Key 'HKCR\CLSID\{9F34AF20-6095-11D3-8FB2-00C04F8EC627}\InProcServer32' is missing.
Key 'HKCR\CLSID\{9F34AF20-6095-11D3-8FB2-00C04F8EC627}\InProcServer32' is missing.


-----------
USB Devices
-----------

----------------
Gameport Devices
----------------

------------
PS/2 Devices
------------

----------------------------
DirectPlay Service Providers
----------------------------
DirectPlay8 Modem Service Provider - Registry: OK, File: dpnet.dll (5.03.0000.0900)
DirectPlay8 Serial Service Provider - Registry: OK, File: dpnet.dll (5.03.0000.0900)
DirectPlay8 IPX Service Provider - Registry: OK, File: dpnet.dll (5.03.0000.0900)
DirectPlay8 TCP/IP Service Provider - Registry: OK, File: dpnet.dll (5.03.0000.0900)

DirectPlay Voice Wizard Tests: Full Duplex: Not run, Half Duplex: Not run, Mic: Not run
DirectPlay Test Result: Not run
Registry: OK

-------------------
DirectPlay Adapters
-------------------
DirectPlay8 Serial Service Provider: COM1
DirectPlay8 Serial Service Provider: COM2
DirectPlay8 Serial Service Provider: COM3
DirectPlay8 Serial Service Provider: COM4

-----------------------
DirectPlay Voice Codecs
-----------------------

-------------------------
DirectPlay Lobbyable Apps
-------------------------

------------------------
Disk & DVD/CD-ROM Drives
------------------------
      Drive: C:
 Free Space: 861.3 GB
Total Space: 78.4 GB
File System: NTFS
      Model: n/a

      Drive: D:
      Model: Wine CD-ROM ATA Device

------------------
DirectX Components
------------------
   ddraw.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 3236 bytes
 ddrawex.dll:                 Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 1924 bytes
   dxapi.sys: missing!
    d3d8.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2456 bytes
 d3d8thk.dll: missing!
    d3d9.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2456 bytes
   d3dim.dll: 5.03.2180.0014 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2516 bytes
d3dim700.dll: missing!
   d3drm.dll: 5.00.2134.0014 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2512 bytes
  d3dxof.dll: 5.00.2135.0001 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 49424 bytes
d3dpmesh.dll: missing!
   dplay.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2492 bytes
  dplayx.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 English Final Retail 7/9/2004 04:27:28 230400 bytes
dpmodemx.dll: missing!
dpwsockx.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 Chinese (Traditional) Final Retail 7/9/2004 04:27:28 79360 bytes
dplaysvr.exe: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 28160 bytes
  dpnsvr.exe: missing!
   dpnet.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 Chinese (Traditional) Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 723968 bytes
dpnlobby.dll: 5.03.2600.2180 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2488 bytes
 dpnaddr.dll: 5.03.2600.2180 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2484 bytes
 dpvoice.dll: missing!
dpvsetup.exe: missing!
  dpvvox.dll: missing!
  dpvacm.dll: missing!
dpnhpast.dll: 5.03.0000.0901 English Final Retail 3/24/2003 10:00:02 32768 bytes
dpnhupnp.dll: missing!
  dinput.dll: 5.01.2600.0881 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 30384 bytes
 dinput8.dll: 5.01.2600.0881 Chinese (Traditional) Final Retail 10/30/2001 09:10:00 664576 bytes
   dimap.dll: missing!
diactfrm.dll: missing!
     joy.cpl: 10.00.0000.0000 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 75136 bytes
   gcdef.dll: missing!
  dsound.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 Chinese (Traditional) Final Retail 7/9/2004 04:27:28 381952 bytes
dsound3d.dll: missing!
  dswave.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 18432 bytes
   dsdmo.dll: missing!
dsdmoprp.dll: missing!
  dmusic.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 Chinese (Traditional) Final Retail 7/9/2004 04:27:28 122880 bytes
  dmband.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 27136 bytes
dmcompos.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 58368 bytes
   dmime.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 English Final Retail 7/9/2004 04:27:28 181248 bytes
dmloader.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 33280 bytes
 dmstyle.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 98816 bytes
 dmsynth.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 100864 bytes
dmscript.dll: 5.03.0000.0900 English Final Retail 12/12/2002 01:14:32 76800 bytes
   dx7vb.dll: missing!
   dx8vb.dll: missing!
 dxdiagn.dll: 5.03.0001.0904 Chinese (Traditional) Final Retail 7/9/2004 04:27:28 1769472 bytes
 wsock32.dll: 4.00.0000.0000 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2444 bytes
amstream.dll: 6.05.0001.0900 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 3344 bytes
 devenum.dll: 6.05.0001.0902 Chinese (Traditional) Final Retail 5/30/2003 09:00:02 132608 bytes
mciqtz32.dll: 6.05.0001.0900 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 13396 bytes
   msdmo.dll: 6.05.0001.0900 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2440 bytes
  encapi.dll: missing!
    qasf.dll: missing!
    qcap.dll: 6.05.0001.0900 English Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2444 bytes
     qdv.dll: missing!
    qdvd.dll: missing!
   qedit.dll:                 Final Retail 7/2/2014 14:49:32 2096 bytes (problem)
qedwipes.dll: missing!
  quartz.dll: 6.05.0001.0902 Chinese (Traditional) Final Retail 5/30/2003 09:00:02 1962496 bytes

------------------
DirectShow Filters
------------------

DirectShow Filters:
Full Screen Renderer,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Color Space Converter,0x00400001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
AVI Splitter,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
VGA 16 Color Ditherer,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
GStreamer YUV filter,0x00400000,1,1,winegstreamer.dll,0.00.0001.0000
MJPEG Decompressor,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
GStreamer AudioConvert filter,0x00400000,1,1,winegstreamer.dll,0.00.0001.0000
MPEG-I Stream Splitter,0x00600000,1,2,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
SAMI (CC) Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Internal Script Command Renderer,0x00800001,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
MPEG Audio Decoder,0x03680001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Video Mixing Renderer 9,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
ACM Wrapper,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Video Renderer,0x00800001,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Video Port Manager,0x00600000,2,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Video Renderer,0x00400000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
GStreamer Mp3 filter,0x00600000,1,1,winegstreamer.dll,0.00.0001.0000
Audio Renderer,0x00800000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
AVI Draw,0x00600064,9,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Null Renderer,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
AVI Decompressor,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
AVI/WAV File Source,0x00400000,0,2,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
QuickTime Movie Parser,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Wave Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
MIDI Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Multi-file Parser,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
File stream renderer,0x00400000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Audio Renderer,0x00800000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Line 21 Decoder 2,0x00600002,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
File Source (Async.),0x00400000,0,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
File Source (URL),0x00400000,0,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
GStreamer splitter filter,0x00800000,1,2,winegstreamer.dll,0.00.0001.0000
QT Decompressor,0x00600000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
MPEG Video Decoder,0x40000001,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902

Video Compressors:
MJPEG Compressor,0x00200000,0,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Kodek Cinepak Video,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.05.0001.0900
Kodek wideo Wine MS-RLE,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.05.0001.0900
Kodek Wine Video 1,0x00200000,1,1,qcap.dll,6.05.0001.0900

Audio Compressors:
IMA ADPCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
PCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Microsoft ADPCM,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
GSM 6.10,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
A-Law,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
U-Law,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
MPeg,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
MPeg3,0x00200000,1,1,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902

Audio Capture Sources:
In: default,0x00200000,0,0,qcap.dll,6.05.0001.0900
In: HDA Intel PCH - CX20757 Ana,0x00200000,0,0,qcap.dll,6.05.0001.0900

Midi Renderers:
Default MidiOut Device,0x00800000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Midi Through Port-0,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902

Video Capture Sources:
Lenovo EasyCamera,0x00200000,0,0,qcap.dll,6.05.0001.0900

Audio Renderers:
Out: default,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Default DirectSound Device,0x00800000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Default WaveOut Device,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
DirectSound: Out: default,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
DirectSound: Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 0,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
DirectSound: Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 1,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
DirectSound: Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 2,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
DirectSound: Out: HDA Intel PCH - CX20757 Analog,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 0,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 1,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Out: HDA Intel HDMI - HDMI 2,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
Out: HDA Intel PCH - CX20757 An,0x00200000,1,0,quartz.dll,6.05.0001.0902
```

I have added all neccesarry libraries to winecfg. `glxgears` works propely. Please help me in my case. My OS is Debian Jessie, Wine version - 1.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the [Windows API implementation - OpenGL module](https://packages.debian.org/es/jessie/libwine-gl) is installed. This contains modules that allow Windows applications to use 3D acceleration in WINE. It's package is `libwine-gl` in the Debian (>= 6.0) repositories.

If using Debian x86_64 (with [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)), then the command is:

```
apt-get install libwine-gl:i386
```

Else:

```
apt-get install libwine-gl
```